# Cannot open IIS 7 applicationHost.config in 64-bit Windows with 32-bit text editor

Tags: iis

Why can I not open the applicationhost.config file on 64-bit Windows?

Comment: Are you receiving an error message? By default, to edit applicationHost.config, you need to be running your editor of choice (ie Notepad) as administrator since it is within System directory.

Answer (score 7):

Paraphrased from [icelava.net forums](http://icelava.net/forums/thread/5391.aspx):

Under x64 Windows certain paths are designated as 64-bit paths, and a 32-bit process, like Visual Studio, is being redirected by Windows to the 32-bit path at C:\windows\SysWOW64 whenever C:\windows\system32 is referenced. The 32-bit process thinks it is looking at C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config when it has been given C:\windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\config; which indeed contain none of those configuration files we are after.

To solve (credit to Robert McMurray):

Open a 64-bit command prompt and execute the following commands:

```
cd /d "%systemdrive%\windows\syswow64\inetsrv"

move config configx86

MKLINK /d Config "%systemdrive%\windows\system32\inetsrv\Config"
```

It should report

```
symbolic link created for Config <<===>> C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\Config
```

This effectively renames the 32-bit config directory so a symbolic link of that name can take its place to redirect back to the 64-bit path which we are really interested in.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with redirections defined for WoW (Windows on Windows), aka to have older 32-bit apps still work inside 64-bit Windows.

Quoting from https://github.com/simonsteele/pn/issues/174

> File system redirection. PN is 32-bit. Try
>   \Windows\sysnative\inetsrv\config instead.